# Static Website Hosting on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Hosting a website on AWS,it is not redirecting my www.example.com site to example.com.'example' is substituted for the actual site. I went through all tutorials, but I couldn't figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

https://discoposse.com/2016/08/12/simple-http-redirects-using-aws-route-53-and-s3/

You need to setup redirection rules under a different bucket and forward to the root domain.

Hope it helps.